# Using Variable/Range as Worksheet and Table name

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am working with a workbook where you can choose a list of countries in a dropdown menu.
When changing the name, the Pivot table is updated to the corresponding Worksheet and Table.
The Pivot updating works and it changes the source depending on the country chosen.

The next step is that I want some data from the table that we connected to the worksheet to do some calculations.
If I choose the name of the worksheet and table directly in the "set" step, they are not changing depending on my dropdown selection.

```vb
Sub NORDICS()

Dim tblName As String
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ams As Long
Dim Target As Variant
Dim average As Variant
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Nordics")
Set tbl = ws1.ListObjects("TableNordics")

''What is the Table Name
Range("E3").Formula = "=""Table""&F3"

''Set tblName to the "calculated" table name above
tblName = Range("E3")

''Update the source to "PivotTable1" to be the tblName
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    tblName, Version:=6)
        
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Points(53).Select
    Selection.Format.Line.EndArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadStealth
    
''Collect the Last row of the Table Body
ans = tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count

''Collect the Last cell value of column 8 and last row calculated above
Target = tbl.DataBodyRange(ans, 8).Value

''Collect the Total Rows Value from the Table
With tbl
    average = .TotalsRowRange.Cells(.ListColumns.Count).Value
End With

''Calculate the average vs Target value and put in "W3"
Range("W3") = average - Target
    
''Remove Calculations done on worksheet that is not needed any more
Range("E3").Formula = "="""""
Range("E3").Value = Range("E3").Value
    
End Sub
```

My end goal would be that

```vb
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Nordics")
Set tbl = ws1.ListObjects("TableNordics")
```

is

```vb
Set ws1 = Worksheets = Range("F3")
Set tbl = ws1.ListObjects = Range("E3")
```

Comment: `Set ws1 = Worksheets(Range("F3").Value2)` and `Set tbl = ws1.ListObjects(Range("E3").Value2)`

Comment: @chrisneilsen Thank you! I understood there were something I was missing, and it was simple as well! :D